# Probability: find the values to make E minimal for a probability space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm currently learning probability modeling but just get stuck at the following question, could anyone help me with it? Thanks a lot!

Let $X, Y ∈ L^2(\Omega, F, P)$ be real-valued random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$. Determine all the values $a, b ∈ R$ such that $E((Y-a-bX)^2)$ is minimal as a function of a and b.

I'm thinking about considering $X=0$ but then just don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not set $X=0$, as this is an assumption that we cannot afford.

On the other hand, consider the nature of the expected value. You are taking the expected value of the square of an expression, so surely the expected value must be non-negative. It is minimal when it is $0$.

If $Y=a+bX$ then you have achieved minimality, and one can easily see what the values of $a$ and $b$ need to be at this point.